# Is it possible to support multiple page actions from the same browser extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I have a set of related page actions. I would like multiple menu options to appear in the page action list, and I'd rather not create separate extensions for each one.

Is it possible to:

1. Create multiple page actions in the menu from a single extension (question: how would the `OnClick` event work?)
2. Create a flyout menu like the "Send Tab to Device >" flyout that appears by default

[image: A view of the default page action menu in Firefox]

Comment: Only one popup can be active at a time, see browser.pageAction.setPopup. You can display a list in the context menu, see browser.menus.

Comment: See the image I just added. See how "Send Tab to Device" has a submenu flyout?  Is that possible from an extension I write myself, or is that baked into Firefox?

Comment: Extensions can organize their menus in submenus. You can find an example if the documentation is not obvious. In short, you need to specify the parent id when creating child items.